# What are the password requirements for a private rubygems repository?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there any way to have a password containing `#` or `@` in the sources section of a `.gemrc` file?

I have tried to encode them as `%3A` and `%40`, but then I get an Unauthorization 401 error.

If it's not possible, what are the rules I must define for an acceptable RubyGems private repository password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the way `gem` or more specifically [`Gem::RemoteFetcher`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb) in Ruby versions [before 2.1](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/lib/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb) handle a request with escaped characters in the `userinfo` section of the URI.

You can view the Base64 encoded basic auth info that is being sent using a proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and watching `gem` complete a request via the proxy.

Using `admin:admin` you get

```
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

Then using `admin:a%64min` you get extra characters:

```
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YSU2NG1pbg==
```

Which turns out to be:

```
irb(main):012:0> Base64.decode64 'YWRtaW46YSU2NG1pbg==' 
=> "admin:a%64min"
```

So if you `%` encode characters, they are passed through to basic auth directly as if the password contained the `%XX` characters. Then when you don't escape the userinfo, the URI string parsing will fail.

Ruby 2.1 onwards seems to have restructured the code so it passes the original `URI` object all the way through to the request, rather than trying to [build authorisation from a URI object in the request](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/lib/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb#L480-L482).

#### Allowed characters

[Here is the code for allowed userinfo characters in 1.9.3](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/lib/uri/common.rb#L408-L410). It boils down to:

```
[a-zA-Z\d\\-_.!~*'();:&=+$,]
```

#### Testing with `gem sources`

#### 1.9.3

```
$ rbenv shell 1.9.3-p545
$ gem sources -V -a 'http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/'
GET http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/specs.4.8.gz
401 Unauthorized
Error fetching http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/:
        bad response Unauthorized 401 (http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/specs.4.8.gz)
```

#### 2.0.0

```
$ rbenv shell 2.0.0-p481
$ gem sources -V -a 'http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/'
GET http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/specs.4.8.gz
401 Unauthorized
Error fetching http://admin:a%23min@10.1.1.140:3000/:
        bad response Unauthorized 401 (http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/specs.4.8.gz)
```

#### 2.1.2

```
$ rbenv shell 2.1.2
$ gem sources -V -a 'http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/'
GET http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/specs.4.8.gz
404 Not Found
Error fetching http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/:
        bad response Not Found 404 (http://admin:a%23min@localhost:3000/specs.4.8.gz)
```

The 404 was expected as this was a simple Rack shim responding rather than a real gem host.